# how to handle a long interrupt without freezing the system

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pid, interrupt-handling

I am implementing an interrupt handling that can close an opening txt file from a Linux kernel module.
I am able to get the txt file path(See picture). However, when I try to close that file, my computer is always freezing.
I use close_fd() but it does not work
[Result from dmesg, a txt file is detected in pid 10367](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCIit.png)
Here is my code:

```
for_each_process(task_list) {
    pr_info("Process: %s\t PID:[%d]\t State:%s\n", 
            task_list->comm, task_list->pid,
            get_task_state(task_list->state));
    if (task_list->files == NULL) continue; // Ignore processes without files
    fdt = files_fdtable(task_list->files);
    int i=0;
    while(fdt->fd[i] != NULL) { 
        files_path = fdt->fd[i]->f_path;
        mode_path = fdt->fd[i]->f_mode;
        cwd = d_path(&files_path,buf,100*sizeof(char));

        printk(KERN_INFO "Open file with fd %d  %s mode: %d", i,cwd, mode_path);
        //Suppose that I can detect a txt file is running in pid 10367. And I want to safety close it
        if (task_list->pid == 10367){
            printk(KERN_INFO "This below function does not work");
            close_fd(fdt->fd[i]); 
        }  
        i++;
    }
}
```

I don't know what steps that I made the mistake. Could someone review and support me?
Best regards

Comment: close writes out all buffered data. This is about 1000000 times slower than an interrupt should take. rethink your design

Comment: File descriptors are local to each process. The parameter of `close_fd` is only valid for the `current` task's process. Also, I doubt that it can be called from an interrupt context.

Comment: Hi @stark, 
thanks for your comments. My task is to close all opening descriptor files after receiving an Interrupt signal in a very sort time. Do you have any suggestions on what I should do to close fd and avoid hanging issue?

Comment: Hello @IanAbbott
Thanks. I agree, I have tried so many times. This close_fd() does not work in my Linux kernel module. If you know another way to close opening fd. Plz share it with me

Comment: Interrupt routine should set a flag that fds need to be closed. Lower priority task should do the close.

Comment: @stark is mostly right; but set a flag, implying polling is a bit crude.   Ideally, you would like your process (10367) to be waiting on something like a semaphore, and have your interrupt handler release the semaphore; thus permitting 10367 to run.  When it runs, it should close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. It is `filp_close()`

```
flush_cache_all() ;             
close_result = filp_close(fdt->fd[i], NULL);
```

The whole system will not be frozen.
Thank you very much for your suggestions.
Regards